# MASM: A1000 error, unable to open file (assembly)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly, masm

I have a Visual Studio 2017 project, where I'm trying to interface a C++ and Assembly program. So I have a header ("indexof.h") that has the Prototypes for the assembly procedures in an `extern "C"` block, and a main.cpp, which includes `indexof.h` and uses the procedures made available in it, and then an `IndexOf.asm` file that contains my assembly code (which also has prototypes for its procedures, before the .code section). Unfortunately, when I attempt to run it, I get this error:

```
1>Assembling IndexOf.asm...
1>MASM : fatal error A1000: cannot open file : IndexOf.asm
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\BuildCustomizations\masm.targets(50,5): error MSB3721: The command "ml.exe /c /nologo /Zf /Zi /Fo"Debug\IndexOf.obj" /W3 /errorReport:prompt  /TaIndexOf.asm" exited with code 1.
1>Done building project "IndexOf_asm.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

I desperately need help (It's due tomorrow), this was a project setup provided by my class, I'm just trying to run it, and I haven't even gotten to the actual thing I need to do yet. Thank you!

Comment: If you have an `IndexOf.asm` it apparently is not where the project expects it to be. If the project is copied from elsewhere, perhaps the paths are different from the original location.

Comment: Hm. Good point. How should I check that?

Comment: If you look at the error though, it looks like its using a relative path.